# How To Implement Perspective Projection

Tags: java, perspectivecamera

I have a mini-project of Ray-Tracing I've started writing in Java.

I have implemented everything by my self without any libraries like OpenGl, everything was implemented by me from scratch - the Camera, Renderer, Image Writer etc...
The thing is, when I place an object - let's say - a sphere, that is not positioned in the center of the screen, it's getting some sort of elliptic shape. same for (finite) cylinder - it stretches radially for some reason.

The rendering process goes like this:
my Camera is defined with origin point, direction and up vectors, the right vector is the cross product direction X up.
for each point in the view plane, I construct a ray from that point to the origin of the camera, and shoot it to find intersections with each geometry in the scene. for each geometry, I take the closest intersection point, calculate its color, and write its color to the the pixel located at that point of the view plane (which I constructed a ray from).

Now, I've read a lot about Perspective Projection, and I've tried to implement one using this link: http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial12/tutorial12.html
But failed to use it.
I've implemented it in my Transform class, and what I tried to do is to multiply the Projection Matrix M by any closest intersection point p I've found in my scene. 
Unfortunately, the result stays the same for some reason.

NOTE: The multiplication of M*p is a new vector4 (v1,v2,v3,v4) such that it's trasformed to a new vector3 (v1/v4, v2/v4, v3/v4).
So the return value of that multiplication is that vector3.

To calculate the field of view angle θ, I calculated the angle between the 2 rays to the 2 sides of the view plane.

**HERE IS SOME CODE**
GitHub link if its too messy here: https://github.com/elyasaf755/3D-Engine

**My Transform class fields and its relevant functions**:

```java
public class Transform {
    private static double _zNear;
    private static double _zFar;
    private static double _width;//screen width
    private static double _height;//screen height
    private static double _fov;//field of view

    private Vector3D _translation;
    private Vector3D _rotation;
    private Vector3D _scale;

    public Matrix4 getTransformation(){
        Matrix4 translationMatrix = new Matrix4().initTranslation(
                this._translation.getPoint().getX().getCoord(),
                this._translation.getPoint().getY().getCoord(),
                this._translation.getPoint().getZ().getCoord()
        );

        Matrix4 rotationMatrix = new Matrix4().initRotation(
                _rotation.getPoint().getX().getCoord(),
                _rotation.getPoint().getY().getCoord(),
                _rotation.getPoint().getZ().getCoord()
        );

        Matrix4 scaleMatrix = new Matrix4().initScale(
                _scale.getPoint().getX().getCoord(),
                _scale.getPoint().getY().getCoord(),
                _scale.getPoint().getZ().getCoord()
        );

        return translationMatrix.mult(rotationMatrix.mult(scaleMatrix));
    }

    public Matrix4 getProjectedTransformation(){

        Matrix4 transformationMatrix = getTransformation();
        Matrix4 projectionMatrix = new Matrix4().initProjection(_fov, _width, 
                                                    _height, _zNear, _zFar);

        return projectionMatrix.mult(transformationMatrix);
    }
}
```

**My Matrix4 class fields and its relevant functions**:

```java
public class Matrix4 {
    private double[][] _m;

    public Matrix4 initProjection(double fov, double width, double height, 
                                             double zFar, double zNear){

        double ar = width / height;
        double tanHalfFov = Math.tan(Math.toRadians(fov / 2));
        double zRange = zNear - zFar;

        setRow(0,1 / (tanHalfFov * ar),0,           0,                     0);
        setRow(1,0,                    1/tanHalfFov,0,                     0);
        setRow(2,0,                    0,           (-zNear - zFar) / zRange,2 
                                                     * zFar * zNear / zRange);
        setRow(3,0,                    0,           1,                     0);

        return this;
    }

    public Matrix4 mult(Matrix4 matrix) {
        Matrix lhs = new Matrix(_m);
        Matrix rhs = new Matrix(matrix.getMatrix());

        Matrix result = lhs.mult(rhs);//simple matrix multiplication


        return new Matrix4(result.get_matrix());
     }
}
```

**My Matrix class fields and its relevant functions**:

```java
public class Matrix {
    private double[][] _matrix;
    private int _numOfRows;
    private int _numOfCols;

    public Matrix mult(Matrix matrix) {
        if (_numOfCols != matrix.getRows())
            return null;

        Matrix result = new Matrix(_numOfRows, matrix.getColumns());


        for (int i = 0; i < _numOfRows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.getColumns(); j++)
            {
                BigDecimal sum = new BigDecimal(0, MathContext.UNLIMITED);

                for (int k = 0; k < matrix.getRows(); k++)
                {
                    BigDecimal temp = new BigDecimal(
                                      _matrix[i][k]*matrix.get_element(k, j), 
                                      MathContext.UNLIMITED);
                    sum = sum.add(temp);
                }

                Coordinate temp = new Coordinate(sum.doubleValue());

                result.set_element(i, j, temp.getCoord());
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

**My Camera class fields and its relevant functions**:

```
public class Camera {
private Point3D _origin;
private Vector3D _direction;
private Vector3D _up;
private Vector3D _right;

public Ray constructRayThroughPixel(int Nx, int Ny, int i, int j, double 
                screenDistance, double screenWidth, double screenHeight){
    //Fix pixel locations
    i = Nx - i - 1;
    //j = Ny - j;


    Point3D p0 = get_origin();
    Vector3D direction = get_direction();
    Vector3D up = get_up();
    Vector3D right = get_right();

    //Image center point
    Point3D Pc = p0.add(direction.scale(screenDistance));

    //Pixel ratios
    double Rx = screenWidth / Nx; //Pixel width
    double Ry = screenHeight / Ny; //Pixel height

    //Center pixel
    double Xi = (i - Nx / 2.0)*Rx + Rx / 2.0;
    double Yj = (j - Ny / 2.0)*Ry + Ry / 2.0;

    Point3D p_ij;
    if (Xi == 0 && Yj == 0){
        p_ij = new Point3D(Pc);
    }
    else if (Xi == 0){
        p_ij = new Point3D(Pc.add(Vector3D.ZERO.subtract(up.scale(Yj))));
    }
    else if (Yj == 0){
        p_ij = new Point3D(
               Pc.add((right.scale(Xi)).subtract(Vector3D.ZERO)));
    }
    else{
        p_ij = new Point3D
               (Pc.add((right.scale(Xi)).subtract(up.scale(Yj))));
    }

    Vector3D v_ij = p_ij.subtract(p0);

    return new Ray(p0, v_ij.normalized());
}
```

}

I expect any object to keep its original shape after rendering it, no matter its position.

When the sphere is not centered
[image: When the sphere is not centered]

When the sphere is centered
[image: When the sphere is centered]

One thing I can do is to make the camera really really far from the objects so I wont notice those stretches. But I want to fix this from the ground.

Comment: Both images look just right to me. Imagine the circular cone from the camera to the sphere. In the first image, the cone intersects the camera plane orthogonally, in a circle. In the second image, the cone is tilted, so it intersects the camera plane in an ellipse. This is just how perspective projection works, you can't "fix" it because it's not wrong. If you doubt me, just launch any first-person 3D game that contains spheres, then tilt your camera around and look at the sphere's shape on your monitor.

Comment: The distortion, as you've figured out, is caused by things on screen appearing at a sharp angle, because your camera has a high FOV. If you don't like that, then you can lower your FOV to mitigate that. But remember that if you look at your screen from an angle, circles will also appear distorted, but in exactly the opposite manner. So if your renderer's FOV is set to the actual FOV of your viewport window as seen from your own eyes, then both these distortions cancel out exactly and your spheres will appear circular again (even though they are ellipses on the screen).

Comment: I dont know. Back then when I played with unity - I've never encountered that issue. 3D elements are always stays the same no matter the rotation/scale what so ever. For now to fix this I just put the camera 10,000 units far from the begining of the scence...